# Script to parse a lua file

Tags: bash, lua

I have a file coming from a XMPP prosody server that logs messages in a room. This file looks like this:

```
item({
    {
        "Test1";
        ["attr"] = {};
        ["name"] = "body";
    };
    {
        ["name"] = "origin-id";
        ["attr"] = {
            ["id"] = "36cface5-e780-4594-b859-03ff635263bc";
            ["xmlns"] = "urn:xmpp:sid:0";
        };
    };
    ["with"] = "message<groupchat";
    ["name"] = "message";
    ["when"] = 1565197939;
    ["key"] = "U5KzbmuUEQN4QCIN";
    ["attr"] = {
        ["stamp_legacy"] = "20190807T17:12:19";
        ["type"] = "groupchat";
        ["to"] = "help@room.myserver.com";
        ["from"] = "help@room.myserver.com/myusername";
        ["id"] = "36cface5-e780-4594-b859-03ff635263bc";
        ["stamp"] = "2019-08-07T17:12:19Z";
        ["xml:lang"] = "en";
    };
});
item({
    {
        "Test 2\n";
        ["attr"] = {};
        ["name"] = "body";
    };
    {
        ["name"] = "origin-id";
        ["attr"] = {
            ["id"] = "fc944764-2fd3-4102-a5d0-1572163baa2b";
            ["xmlns"] = "urn:xmpp:sid:0";
        };
    };
    ["with"] = "message<groupchat";
    ["name"] = "message";
    ["when"] = 1565198050;
    ["key"] = "DH3THj8R4QcIkFsm";
    ["attr"] = {
        ["stamp_legacy"] = "20190807T17:14:10";
        ["type"] = "groupchat";
        ["to"] = "help@room.myserver.com";
        ["from"] = "help@room.myserver.com/myusername";
        ["id"] = "fc944764-2fd3-4102-a5d0-1572163baa2b";
        ["stamp"] = "2019-08-07T17:14:10Z";
        ["xml:lang"] = "en";
    };
});
```

I would like to create a bash script that would create a file like this:

```
Date, Hour, Username, Message
Date, Hour, Username, Message
Date, Hour, Username, Message
```

So that it would be easier to read the discussion.

That means that it should select for each item:

```
For Date, Hour: ["stamp"]
For username: ["from"]
For message: what is between the first quotes, so for example "Test1"  or Test 2\n
```

I don't know how to do that. sed? awk? something else?

Comment: You'd need to go from the specification for that file type, not the data you see in an example, or you risk missing something - unless the file _always_ looks exactly like that structure.  I wrote an XML parser in bash from scratch a while back, which would be a similar process, and it was certainly non-trivial.

Comment: At the risk of being downvoted because I don't answer the question: This is Lua (data stored by the prosody XMPP server), you should avoid trying to parse this in bash. A solution would be to read this in Lua first to be able to manipulate the data how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, using bash commands like `sed`, `awk` etc. is first hard and second very risky: it will work only if your data always look exactly like that example.

I would recommend using more advanced tools. But anyway, just for the exercise, here is a bash command that would do what you want *on this specific example only*:

```
cat you_log_file \
   | grep -E '("stamp")|(^ +")|("from")' \
   | sed -E 's/.*=? "(.*)";/\1@@/g' \
   | paste -d\ - - - - \
   | awk -F@@ '{ print substr($3, 2, 10)","substr($3, 13, 8)","$2","$1 }'
```

Output:

```
2019-08-07,17:12:19, help@room.myserver.com/myusername,Test1
2019-08-07,17:14:10, help@room.myserver.com/myusername,Test 2\n
```

Comment: Thanks @Derlin COuld you explain a bit ?

Comment: Also, here is what I get with this command:  
help@room.,yserver., 2019-08-07T17:12:19Z,help@room.myserver.com/myusername
,, -,2019-08-07T17:14:10Z

Comment: I had to change it to cat log.txt    | grep -E '("stamp")|(^ +")|("from")'    | sed -E 's/.*=? "(.*)";/\1@@/g'    | paste -d\ - - -  | awk -F @@ '{ print substr($3, 2, 10)","substr($3, 13, 8)", "$2", "$1 }'

It is better, but still don't get he message, just the dates and usernames